# How to locate for all matches in foxpro 2.6

Tags: foxpro

I'm trying to print all data's that has the same order_number in my table. How to do that? Coz I don't get how to use LOCATE with CONTINUE and SEEK. Thanks for the help. I'm using FoxPro 2.6 BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is very brief and doesn't show the table name, nor any sample data/columns you are interested in.  From what I remember (and this is REALLY going back), Foxpro 2.6 did support SQL querying, but the basic of it would be

```
if used( "C_TmpResult" )
   select C_TmpResult
   use
endif 
select;
      yt.SomeColumn,;
      yt.AnotherCol,;
      yt.AndAnother;
   from ;
      YourTableName as yt ;
   where ;
      yt.OrderNumber = 12345;
   into ;
      cursor C_TmpResult
```

Now, you will have just the data you want.  If you want ALL columns from the table, you don't need to be explicit about all the columns and can just change to

```
select * ;
   from YourTableName ;
   where OrderNumber = 12345 ;
   into cursor C_TmpResult
```

Now, just scan through that.  It is actually a separate "in-memory" version of the table but only the records you care about.  Now, if you have other related tables, such as Sales Order and Sales Order Details, then you need to provide a little more info in your post and show sample table structures and the relations with them.

What do you want to do with the results.. export, just dump, print report?  Edit your original question with more info and I can revise my answer.

Finally, are you using individual indexes (.idx) or compound indexes (.cdx)  I can't remember if FPW26 used .cdx indexes or not.